Render 'InvertedPendulumBulletEnv-v0' from different view - Pybullet, Gym
I trained an RL agent to control an inverted pendulum and wanted to create an animation of it and render the environment. I was able to create the animation and control the pendulum correctly, however I would like to change the camera view and zoom in into the pendulum to better see it, but there seems to be no way to do this.
View of the environment
The image shows the current view
This is the code:
import gym
from sac_torch import Agent
import pybullet_envs
import time

if __name__ == '__main__':

    # Load the environment
    env = gym.make('InvertedPendulumBulletEnv-v0')
    env.render(mode='human')

    # Initialize your agent
    agent = Agent(input_dims=env.observation_space.shape, env=env, n_actions=env.action_space.shape[0])
    agent.load_models()

    # Reset the environment to start
    observation = env.reset()
    done = False
    total_reward = 0

    while not done:
        action = agent.choose_action(observation)
        observation, reward, done, info = env.step(action)
        total_reward += reward
        env.render()
        time.sleep(1. / 60.)  # 60 FPS

    print(f"Total Reward: {total_reward}")

    env.close()


There doesn't seem to be any other input to change the rendering view and the documentation doesn't help either. I have also tried to connect it to Pybullet, but when I do nothin appears on Pybullet, although the simulation runs since at the end I get a reward.
import gym
from sac_torch import Agent
import pybullet as p
import pybullet_envs
import time


def main():
    # Connect to PyBullet
    p.connect(p.GUI)

    # Create the environment
    env = gym.make('InvertedPendulumBulletEnv-v0')

    # Set the camera view
    p.resetDebugVisualizerCamera(
        cameraDistance=2.0,  # Zoom in
        cameraYaw=90,
        cameraPitch=-30,
        cameraTargetPosition=[0, 0, 1]
    )

    # Initialize your agent
    agent = Agent(input_dims=env.observation_space.shape, env=env, n_actions=env.action_space.shape[0])
    agent.load_models()

    # Reset the environment
    observation = env.reset()
    done = False
    total_reward = 0

    while not done:
        action = agent.choose_action(observation)
        observation, reward, done, info = env.step(action)
        total_reward += reward

        # Render the environment
        env.render()

        # Step the simulation
        p.stepSimulation()

        # Pause to control the simulation speed
        time.sleep(1. / 60.)  # 60 FPS

    print(f"Total Reward: {total_reward}")

    # Disconnect from PyBullet
    p.disconnect()

This correctly opens the Pybullet application but doens't render the pendulum in it.
Do you have any idea how to change the view in env.render() or render the simulation correctly on Pybullet?
Thank you for your answers
